# Is there a easy way to check which classes and methods are used in a C# file?

Tags: c#

I want compile C# code at runtime with the CSharpCodeProvider classes and load them as plugins. But I don't want to allow "any" code in them for security reasons, for example it should not be possible to write/read files (just as a example).

What i would like to do is to check the c# file before i compile them and limit the plugin to only uses classes/methods from my api (and maybe some other basic methods like the math class).

So my question: is there a easy way to "scan" a c# file to know which classes/methods are used?

Comment: Take a look at `Roslyn` Project. It is not that easy to understand but very flexible

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Why do you think you need to compile code at runtime?

Comment: @maccettura It's for a game, i want to add "mod" support and allow the player to create custom code based on my api (for example a new spell effect), which is then loaded at runtime. But i don't want to load just any dll, because it could contain insecure code and the "mods" can be shared between players, so i thought the only way to prevent this if i don't load the dll directly but instead the mod should only contain the source file which is then "scanned" before compiling/loading or is there a better solution for this case?

Comment: AppDomain exists for a reason.